# Структура не видит переменную. с++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема с структурой.

сокращенный вариант:

```
class AVL_Tree
    {
    private:

        std::string dirName;//имя директории в которой будет сохранена структура

        struct Tree_ // структура для представления узлов дерева
        {
            Key key;
            Tree_(Key k) {
                key = k;
            //тут был код сохранения , я его удалил чтобы не занимал место
                std::string dir=dirName;
                cout<<dir<<"место хранения структуры"<<endl;
            }
        };     

        Tree_ *root;
    }
```

Не понимаю почему, но `Tree_(Key k)` не видит переменную `dirName`.

> 1)Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   C2327   'lib::AVL_Tree>::dirName': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
>
> 2)Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   C2065   'dirName': undeclared identifier

Не могли бы вы подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: сделай структуру статичной

Comment: не подскажете, что это даст? потому что ошибка не изчезла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш конструктор не знает, к `dirName` **какого объекта** обратиться. Или указывайте объект `AVL_Tree` (передавая его в конструктор, например), или делайте `dirName` членом класса, а не объекта — то есть объявляйте его как `static` и обращайтесь к нему как `AVL_Tree::dirName`.

Comment: Можете дать пример? мне не выгодно просто посылать и вообще хранить `dirName` в структуре. только 1 раз в объекте.

Comment: @Demolver Как я понимаю, ваш узел Tree_ находится в каком-то AVL_Tree. Как вариант - добавьте в структуру поле вроде `AVL_Tree*avl;`, и конструктор делайте `Tree_::Tree_(Key k, AVL_Tree*avl):avl(avl){...}` - примерно так. Тогда к `dirName` вам надо будет обращаться как к `avl->dirName`. На возражение, что не хочется в каждом `Tree_` хранить лишний указатель, задам стречный вопрос - что делать при наличии десятка разных деревьев в программе? Как `Tree_` может знать, в каком он дереве?

Comment: А если передавать в конструктор структуры `dirName`? или же это не красивое решение?

Comment: @Demolver Можно и так. Минус - если что-то еще захотите передавать потом, надо будет многое менять.